# I have been working on this makefile for hours. It keep getting the error: make: *** No rule to make target 'hangman.c', needed by 'hangman.o'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall
CC=gcc

hangman: hangman.o hangman.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hangman.o hangman.c -o hangman

hangman.o: hangman.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c hangman.c

clean:
    rm -f hangman *.o
```

Comment: remove `hangman.c` from lines 4 and 5

Comment: The issue is you're mixing two approaches. You can either compile `c code` -> `obj files` -> `executable`, or directly `c code` -> `executable`. In the first case, you should have two recipes - `hangman: hangman.o` and `hangman.o: hangman.c`. In the second case, only one recipe is needed: `hangman: hangman.c`.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `hangman.c` in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `hangman` (the program binary) only depends of `hangman.o`, but not of `hangman.c`, which has already been compiled into `hangman.o` (at compilation phase).

In `Makefile`, you only state the direct dependencies, while `make(1)` does the rest of the work.

I use to designate all the objects to a program in a variable, as they will be used several times.  In this way:

```
# Makefile -- make file for hangman.

targets = hangman

hangman_objs = hangman.o

hangman: $(hangman_objs)
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o hangman $(hangman_objs)
```

and nothing else, as `make(1)` has an automatic rule, that is

```
.c.o:
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

which is the equivalent to this rule:

```
hangman.o: hangman.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o hangman.o -c hangman.c
```

(and the same for each `.c` and `.o` file you can have.)

By the way, the error you are receiving, is that make has found a dependency on `hangman.c` but doesn't find any file called `hangman.c` so it needs to build it, but you don't provide this file.  You have probably erased your `hangman.c` file (which is something that sometimes happen if you mispell files in the `Makefile`, make ends erasing files that are important for you)  In this case, it tries to build `handman` which depends on `handman.o` which depends on `handman.c`, so no finding `handman.c` makes `make(1)` to say, I have a dependency on `handman.c` but no such file is found (and I have no dependency to follow that allows me to build it)

If your project is a single source project, then you can avoid the generation of `hangman.o` and create a `Makefile` like this:

```
hangman: hangman.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o hangman hangman.c
```

Which states an explicit, direct reference from the binary to the source code.  In this case, you don't use the `-c` flag to the compiler to *just compile, and don't link*, and build your executable directly with one command.  This is not used in large projects, as normally you want to just compile the sources that have changed.  As in this example:

```
hangman_objs = hang.o man.o foo.o bar.o a.o b.o c.o

hangman: $(hangman_objs)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o hangman $(hangman_objs)
```

if you expand the variable, you'll get this rule:

```
hangman: hang.o man.o foo.o bar.o a.o b.o c.o
        cc  -o hangman hang.o man.o foo.o bar.o a.o b.o c.o

#all this are automatic dependencies generated from
#  .c.o:
#       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
# for the files hang.o man.o foo.o bar.o a.o b.o c.o

hang.o: hang.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c hang.c -o hang.o
man.o: man.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c man.c -o man.o
foo.o: foo.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c foo.c -o foo.o
bar.o: bar.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c bar.c -o bar.o
a.o: a.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c a.c -o a.o
b.o: b.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c b.c -o b.o
c.c: c.c
        cc -O2 -pipe -c c.c -o c.o
```

but you must not use both, the object code and the source code in the linking phase of your program.  The compiler will link the file you provide `hangman.o` and will compile it also (which generates a new `hangman.o`) and will try to link both (two versions of the same code) and that can generate new errors.

My approach to your program would be:

```
# main targets to build (programs)
targets     =    hangman

# toclean maintains everything must be erased on clean.
toclean     = $(targets)

# object files of hangman target
hangman_objs = hangman.o foo.o

# add all those objects to the toclean variable.
toclean += $(hangman_objs)

# libraries
hangman_ldflags = -L path/to/libbar
hangman_libs = -lbar

# main target all
all: $(targets)
# ... and clean
clean:
        rm -f $(toclean)

# just the link phase, the compiling is automatically done.
hangman: $(hangman_objs)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $($@_ldflags) -o $@ $($@_objs) $($@_libs)
```